# Creating GUI for a previous project

Tags: java, swing

Really getting caught up here. Need to make a GUI for the program I have already made but am confused as to how to include the GUI "package"? I've included all my code, and 2 java files (help1/help2)that were given to me or i've been working off of. Is Juserinterface supposed to be made as a separate project or class? I just cant seem to put it all together!

my code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9160178

program outline https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2CQYYNDU3ozQlAyaVZRbTZJLTQ&usp=drive_web

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look up the Classes for Swing

Answer (score 1):

Swing and JavaFX follow the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) paradigm, this separates the logic of the user interface (view) from the data (model) and the way that the view and model can change each other (control)

Also, Java also encourages the use of a separate class file for each object.  While you can you use inner classes, these should be providing support, in some way, to the parent class, generally.

So, having said all that, yes, you should place you UI base classes into separate files.  I might even encourage you to use a separate package, but that's up to you.

Based on your needs, you should try and see if it's possible to provide some kind of "model" or intermediary between your existing code and the UI, in this way, you might be able to avoid having to rewrite the existing code and the UI can focus on presenting and managing the model.

I would suggest starting with [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).  Converting a program from one paradigm to another is not an easy task and you should also consider rewriting in such away that it can either be used by both applications (the original version and the UI), which improves code reuse and is a great exercise in de-coupling or so you have a model driven version which will work better with the UI framework

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the NetBeans GUI builder which is really easy to use and will save you a lot of time and effort, but if you prefer to do it manually, use:

```
class x extends javax.swing.JFrame
```

Comment: I was looking at that option but I seem to have to it a specific way while adding onto the original project. I just don't know if the userinterface is supposed to be a separate class/program etc.